# Facebook Login - Windows 10 UWP - Desktop

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-10, uwp

I am building a new Universal Windows 10 UWP App, and trying to do a Facebook login.

On Facebook, I have set the Windows App section of my app to have the identifier of my app:

> Windows : s-1-15-xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Windows Phone : fef49b712e5a843cbfeb0c9d780423fc (Not the actual one)

In the package manifest file, I have added the protocol of:

> msft-fef49b712e5a843cbfeb0c9d780423fc

Which means I set my `redirect_uri` parameter to:

> msft-fef49b712e5a843cbfeb0c9d780423fc://authorize

When running on a phone (with Windows 10 Mobile Preview) the service works fine, it opens up the Facebook app on the phone (using fbconnect://authorize?.....), which in turn authenticates, and then opens my app back up - perfect!!

However, when trying the same on the desktop it doesn't work.  In my `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()` is set to have a fallback Uri of the standard Facebook web dialog (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?.....) - This is because there is no Facebook app for Windows 10 that supports login.

Sending the same `redirect_uri` through to Facebook, it opens up the web browser (Edge) and asks for permissions etc.  once the permissions have been given, nothing happens.  It seems as though the protocol handling isn't working.

Any thoughts would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On desktop, try using the `WebAuthenticationBroker` instead of `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` as described in this example: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.de/2015/06/custom-oauth-login-to-facebook-for.html

```
private async Task<string> AuthenticateFacebookAsync()
{
  try
  {
    var fb = new FacebookClient();

    var redirectUri = 
      WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();

    var loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
                                   {
                                     client_id = AppId,
                                     redirect_uri = redirectUri,
                                     scope = ExtendedPermissions,
                                     display = "popup",
                                     response_type = "token"
                                   });

    var callbackUri = new Uri(redirectUri, UriKind.Absolute);

    var authenticationResult =
      await
        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
        WebAuthenticationOptions.None, 
        loginUri, callbackUri);

    return ParseAuthenticationResult(fb, authenticationResult);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return ex.Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does generally work.  However, I do lose  the flexibility of the app being universal.  I was hoping that I would be able to have something that works on both phone and desktop - the best experience for the user will be to authenticate in the app - which means I need the Launcher.LaunchUriAsync - I assume that there is no way of making the fallback for that use the WebAuthenticationBroker?

Comment: `WebAuthenticationBroker` works on both mobile and desktop, so this would be a choice as you cannot require Fb to be installed on mobile as well. The best experience would be the following: 1) check whether the Facebook apps is installed (there's an API for this now in Win 10) and then either use the Fb login or the web auth broker.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting - didn't know you can check to see if an app is installed - do you know what that is?  If I can do that, then you are correct, the `WebAuthenticationBroker` is perfect option after

Comment: [`Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn893515.aspx) should be it. Facebook uses the "fb:" protocol.

Comment: Spot on, thanks - That was obvious now I look at it :)

Comment: Is there way to obtain userid not just access token ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri` for redirect_uri.

And update the same uri in facebook developer console.

[https://developers.facebook.com/apps//settings/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FefNI.png)

[Facebook developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FefNI.png)