# Facebook Single sign on not working in windows phone 8.1 app running on windows 10 devices

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp, win-universal-app, facebook-login, windows-10-universal

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168525/facebook-login-for-windows-phone-8-1/26955236#26955236) link to implement facebook login with facebook app. It works fine. After login from facebook app it redirects to my app.

But when i run this app on windows 10 device facebook app(both latest beta version and latest facebook ) doesnt redirect to my app. Instead facebook beta opens its timeline and facebook app crashes.
 I think `fbconnect://authorize?` is not supported in windows 10 facebook app? But i have got some links in satackoverflow([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098187/facebook-login-windows-10-uwp-desktop)) which says it works fine. But only difference with those links is they have actually created windows 10 universal app where as mine is windows phone 8.1 app running in windows 10

Any ided why this is not working on windows 10 device. Any workaround for this to work?